# Applying transforms to source xaml

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a bit of a problem with XAML and Blend. We;ve converted the company logo from `AI -> SVG -> XAML`, cleaned it up a bit and its has produced a very peculiar source. In essence it is applying a "flip" transformation to a collection of paths:

```
<Canvas Width="640" Height="200" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Canvas Width="640" Height="200" RenderTransform="1,0,0,-1,0,200" >

        <!-- L -->
        <Canvas RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,317.0645,64.3652">
            <Path>
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M0,0L0,75.065 18.743,76.83 18.743,17.066 43.553,17.066 38.564,0 0,0z" />
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
        ... etc
```

Note the `RenderTransform="1,0,0,-1,0,200"` node in the enclosing `Canvas`. It flips the canvas upside down and lowers it 200 down to adjust to root canvas position. Given taht Logo looks ok when rendered means that all graphic elements in the xaml are actually upside down :). Maybe its an AI thing, I don't know.

The problem is that I now use Blend to convert this canvas into a GraphicBrush. The blend omits the transform and the logo looks upiside down when brush is applied. Rather then again transforming at each brush recipient I was thinking that maybe we should just fix it at the root, e.g. convert all paths so that they render properly to begin with avoiding a need for root transform.

Question: is there a programmatic (or any other way) to do this? Meaning, can I render this canvas and then serialize a rendered (after all transforms applied) DOM into an XAML?

Or to make  the question clearer: there are two transforms applied to each path (as seen above, one global flip and one local shift for each path), can I somehow apply those transforms to each path/its points so that paths render without them.

Comment: Seems like the easiest solution would be to use an application like Photoshop to convert your original graphic to vector based graphic.

Comment: Was it a Vector in .AI? Why not just use the .AI -> XAML converter? You might find it will even come out cleaner. http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/

Comment: No, the original .ai was a vector, made in Illustrator, so there is no need to mess with bitmaps. It's part of branding package the company purchased from designers. Unfortunately we do not own an Illustrator license (piracy is not an option), so the only freeware conversion path I found was through svg.

Comment: You can send me your .ai and I'll convert it for you and save all this extra mess. Emails on my profile.

Comment: I'll ask the man upstairs and will let you know if its doable (legal&politics wise). Anyway, thanks for offering.

Comment: It is, and an easy fix to have something proper to work with.

Comment: Just recalled something that might be helpful also. If you have the Expression suite including Expression Design I believe you can literally copy/paste your vectors in to it and use its export to XAML feature also to get a better result still than whatever you used before.

Comment: @ChrisW., thanks, that actually did the trick. Expression Design generated exactly the XAML I was looking for. Can you please write it as an answer, I want to accept it and award you points.

Comment: The weirdest thing is that it appears that ai->svg converter messed things up. Not only transform wise, I now see that it converted 100% Black CMYK color into some shade of gray (faulty conversion formula?), the other colors were also slightly off. The perils of freebies I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Export to XAML feature built in to **Expression Design** in the Microsoft Expression suite.

Or personally I normally use Mike Swanson's [AI to XAML converter](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) since I'm normally already working in Illustrator for more complex vector graphics.

Both would provide a better result than the converter you used. Not sure where that original conversion got so wacky with the RenderTransforms etc but as you've found, it helps to have a good conversion to start with then going through the trouble of fixing a bad one haha.

Cheers!